# Set and get PHP Session on/from the server not on the client

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, client-server

I'm having a problem on depending much on sessions to get a real time update to different computers. So here's the scenario:

[Computer A] Admin page:
If button is clicked, certain text will display on every page of the site, regardless of whose computer's accessing it.

[Computer B] Client page:
I must see the text on my page real time, without loading it whenever the admin clicks the button.

Here's my code:

**Admin page: admin.php**

```
$("#newFight").click(function(){
                var newFight = "newFight="+1;
                $.ajax({
                    type:       "post",
                    url:        "../includes/newfight.php",
                    data:       newFight,
                    cache:      false,
                    success:    function(html){
                        if(html == 0){
                            alert("Open a Game First");
                        }
                        else if(html == 1){
                            $("#newFight").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            // Real time update of fight sequence
                            $("td#fightId").load('../includes/getfight_id.php');
                            $("td#fightHead").html("<em>Fight is on.</em>");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

**Admin page: newfight.php**

```
session_start();
require_once('dbconn.php');
 if(isset($_POST['newFight'])){
        if($_POST['newFight'] == $_SESSION['gameActive']){
            // Make a new fight
            echo $msg = 1;
            $query = "INSERT INTO fights(fight_game_id) VALUES(".$_SESSION['game_id'].")";
            $execQuery = mysql_query($query);
            $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
            $_SESSION['fight_id'] = $last_id;
            $_SESSION['fight_active'] = 1;
        }
        if($_POST['newFight'] != $_SESSION['gameActive']){
            $msg = 0;
            echo $msg;
        }
    }
?>
```

The process here is like this, if a button is clicked, jQuery through AJAX will process it and sets a session ex: $_SESSION['button_clicked'] = 1; for user's reference, so the user's page can be updated real time using setInterval(client's).

And here's the client page that's suppose to get the real time update whenever the admin click the button.

**Client page: client.php**

```
 $(function(){
            var auto_refresh = setInterval(
               function (){
                  $("td#fightHeadUser").load('../includes/fightheaduser.php');
               }, 1000);
 });
```

**Client page: fightheaduser.php**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['fight_active']) && $_SESSION['fight_active'] == 1){
    echo "<em>Fight is on.</em>";
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['fight_active']) && $_SESSION['fight_active'] != 1){
    echo "<em>No fight yet.</em>";
}
```

So my problem is.. it runs only on one computer, so when I open two browsers(admin and client), and clicked the button, I can see that the client's page are updated real time, BUT, when a different computer access the client's page via LAN, it's not working on them. So I suspect that it is because sessions are only stored on my pc that's why it's not woking on other pc.

What do you think I have to do? If you can suggest me a good but different solution, then I would love to try it.

Sorry for my very long question. 
TIA.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not work with sessions to solve this problem as every user (connection) gets another session and can not get the data from the admin session.

you can use environment variables. every connection can read this one.

```
$_ENV
```

Comment: So are you saying that I should replace every $_SESSION in my codes above with $_ENV? Thanks.

Comment: In the code above yes. Only use $_SESSION for user related variables. $_ENV is for global variables.

Comment: Well thanks, will definitely try this once my my hosting is back.

Answer (score 2):

I assume a client has to be login when he want to watch or has a fight? Why not using a db? So u can register which is on, and you can watch history etc. etc.

Comment: Yes they have to be logged in, I also thought about that, but I expect a heavy traffic site, and if I put those on db I think that would totally slows down the application. So as for now I 'm thinking of the fastest possible solution.

Comment: Fair enough, if you expect that your website to have many traffic. But know you only storing a fight ID? nothing else(thats relevant for a fight)?

Comment: Haha, you have a point on that, it's id's only, but the fight button is just one of many buttons on the app, I actually have 15 different buttons that do the same process, storing to db is actually my last choice if ever I totally run off solutions :P

Comment: It is also depending on how you query.. how your structure of your db is etc. etc.. i would suggest then to create 2 databases.. One for all your good data and a "session_db"..

Comment: If you want to do it : http://www.slideshare.net/webhostingguy/session-management-using-mysql-3755192 watch here maybe you have something on this article

Comment: Hehe thanks, I think I'll just use db, for security reasons too :)